# Launcher crashes when running mod in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make my first block in Eclipse, but the launcher crashes whenever I try to run it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've created a new instance of the block, registered it, gave the constructor all the necessary fields, triple-checked the run methods, and I still haven't found the problem. I am running Minecraft 1.7.10.

Here are the classes:

Creates a `BasicBlock` object and registers it:

```
package com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.blocks;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;

public final class ModBlocks {
    public static Block tutorialBlock;

    public static final void init() {
        tutorialBlock = new BasicBlock("tutorialBlock", Material.wood);
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(tutorialBlock, "tutorialBlock");
    }
}
```

BasicBlock class:

```
package com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.blocks;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.Reference;

public class BasicBlock extends Block {
    public BasicBlock(String unlocalizedName, Material material) {
        super(material);
        this.setBlockName(unlocalizedName);
        this.setBlockTextureName(Reference.MOD_ID + ":" + unlocalizedName);
        this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);
        this.setHardness(2.0F);
        this.setResistance(6.0F);
        this.setLightLevel(20.0F);
        this.setHarvestLevel("shovel", 3);
        this.setStepSound(soundTypeMetal);
    }
}
```

Proxy with runtime methods:

```
package com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.proxy;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.*;
import com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.blocks.ModBlocks;
import com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.init.ModItems;

public class CommonProxy {
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent e) {
        ModItems.init();
        ModItems.register();
        ModBlocks.init();
    }

    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent e) {

    }

    public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Main runtime class:

```
package com.mrcrayfish.tutorial;

import com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.init.ModItems;
import com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.proxy.CommonProxy;
import com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.blocks.ModBlocks;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.Instance;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.SidedProxy;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.*;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;

@Mod(modid = Reference.MOD_ID, name = Reference.NAME, version = Reference.VERSION)
public class Tutorial {
    @Instance
    public static Tutorial instance;

    @SidedProxy(clientSide = Reference.CLIENT_PROXY_CLASS, serverSide = Reference.SERVER_PROXY_CLASS)
    public static CommonProxy proxy;

    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        ModItems.init();
        ModItems.register();
        ModBlocks.init();
        proxy.preInit(event);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        System.out.println("init");
        proxy.init(event);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {
        System.out.println("postinit");
        proxy.postInit(event);
    }
}
```

Reference class with final variables/enums:

```
package com.mrcrayfish.tutorial;

import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;

public class Reference {
    public static final String MOD_ID = "ctm";
    public static final String NAME = "MrCrayfish's Tutorial Mod";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";
    public static final String CLIENT_PROXY_CLASS = "com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.proxy.ClientProxy";
    public static final String SERVER_PROXY_CLASS = "com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.proxy.ServerProxy";

    public enum TutorialItems {
        CHEESE("cheese", "ItemCheese");
        public String unlocalizedName;
        public String registryName;

        TutorialItems(String unlocalizedName, String registryName) {
            this.unlocalizedName = unlocalizedName;
            this.registryName = registryName;
        }

        public String getUnlocalizedName() {
            return unlocalizedName;
        }

        public String getRegistryName() {
            return registryName;
        }
    }

    public enum EBlock {
        TUTORIALBLOCK("tutorialBlock", Material.wood);
        String BlockName;
        Material material;

        EBlock(String BlockName, Material material) {
            this.BlockName = BlockName;
            this.material = material;
        }
    }
}
```

ClientProxy class:

```
package com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.proxy;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.*;

public class ClientProxy extends CommonProxy
{
public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent h)
{
    super.preInit(h);
}

public void init(FMLInitializationEvent h)
{
    super.init(h);
}

public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent h)
{
    super.postInit(h);
}
}
```

ServerProxy class:

```
package com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.proxy;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.*;

public class ServerProxy extends CommonProxy
{
public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent h)
{
    super.preInit(h);
}

public void init(FMLInitializationEvent h)
{
    super.init(h);

}

public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent h)
{
    super.postInit(h);
}

}
```

The most I could get out of the debug report is that there is an issue with the "preInit" method in "Tutorial.java". Here's the crash report:

```
at cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.FMLControlledNamespacedRegistry.add(FMLControlledNamespacedRegistry.java:410)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameData.registerItem(GameData.java:849)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameData.registerItem(GameData.java:812)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.registerItem(GameRegistry.java:149)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.registerItem(GameRegistry.java:137)
at com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.init.ModItems.register(ModItems.java:23)
at com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.proxy.CommonProxy.preInit(CommonProxy.java:10)
at com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.proxy.ClientProxy.preInit(ClientProxy.java:8)
at com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.Tutorial.preInit(Tutorial.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:532)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:212)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:190)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:119)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.preinitializeMods(Loader.java:556)
at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:243)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:522)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:942)
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:164)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(Unknown Source)
at GradleStart.main(Unknown Source)
```

After looking through eclipse's console output, I think I can narrow down the issue:

[09:12:27] [Client thread/INFO] [MinecraftForge]: Attempting early MinecraftForge initialization

[09:12:27] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: MinecraftForge v10.13.4.1558 Initialized

[09:12:27] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Replaced 183 ore recipies

[09:12:27] [Client thread/INFO] [MinecraftForge]: Completed early MinecraftForge initialization

[09:12:28] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Found 0 mods from the command line. Injecting into mod discoverer

[09:12:28] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Searching C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Forge\eclipse\mods for mods

[09:12:44] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader has identified 4 mods to load

[09:12:45] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Attempting connection with missing mods [mcp, FML, Forge, ctm] at CLIENT

[09:12:45] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Attempting connection with missing mods [mcp, FML, Forge, ctm] at SERVER

Seems to be an issue with the proxy classes I created.

Comment: Please visit the [help], read [ask] and ESPECIALLY read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: Thanks, and sorry.

Comment: Do you have a crash stackdump?

Comment: There's more wrong here than even a missing crash dump. *What version of Minecraft are you using* is important too, as what your problem is and how to fix it will differ depending on if you're on 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, or 1.12. ALL of those have different possible answers.

Comment: Have you tried running the Java app in the console to see if it has the same behaviour? Is there a message or stacktrace when the application crashed?

Comment: I have a crash report and a debug report, if either of those would help. Currently running 1.7.10.

Comment: The exception stacktrace would be helpful, yes (in the crash report). Are these all your classes? You haven't forgotten to create `ClientProxy` and `ServerProxy` in `com.mrcrayfish.tutorial.proxy`?

Answer (score 0):

When the preInit Event occures you run the following lines

```
 ModItems.init();
 ModItems.register();
 ModBlocks.init();
```

and then you run your Proxies preInit Methode
since bothe the ClientProxy and ServerProxy just call super.preInit
both call CommonProxy's preInit Methode which also does

```
 ModItems.init();
 ModItems.register();
 ModBlocks.init();
```

this means you are trying to register everything twich wich probably causes the error.

Comment: Tried this. Still crashes, with the same error report.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include the part of the error log that includes the actual error, with only the stack trace there is not much more I can do to help

Comment: Late response, but I think I found the issue in the Console output. It seems there's an issue with the mod's server/client proxy class.